# Can I access individual letters in a string, in an array, via index using multiple for loops?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, indices

I'm a newbie of 1 month trying to understand arrays, and how to access them better, I wish to become a master of the for loop with arrays, as it bothers me that IDK how filter, map, and reduce are doing what they're doing.  I'd like to know how to change say the `'M'` in `'Milk'`, to an `'S'`, using a for loop and indices.  Why does the `i` variable in this log `'Top Shelf'` + the contents of the sub-array, instead of just `Top Shelf, Mid-Shelf, Vegetable Drawer, Meat Drawer`?  Why doesn't `console.log([i[k]])` list just the contents of the sub-array within `Top Shelf`?

```
 let fridge = [['Top Shelf', ['Milk', 'Grapes', 'Margarine']], ['Mid-Shelf', ['Beer', 'Eggs', 'Pizza', 'Soda']], ['Vegetable Drawer', ['Celery', 'Broccoli', 'Carrots', 'Lettuce']], ['Meat Drawer', ['Bacon', 'Turkey', 'Ham', 'Chicken']]];

    for(let i = 0; i < fridge.length; i++) {
        for(let k = 0; k < fridge[i].length; k++) {

        }
      console.log(fridge[i[k]])
        }
```

Comment: You should consider using an object instead

Comment: An array is an object. See typeof []

Comment: @Mickers Yes I know - what i mean is this: let fridgeObj = {} - perhaps you haven't seen it

Comment: I understand  your reason for saying so, but the point in my exercise isn't for efficiency or anything, I want to know how to manipulate every aspect i possibly can, of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your code doesn't work because k won't be defined as you're attempting to use it outside of the loop it was declared in.

Second - In order to access individual elements and say change the first letter to an 'S', strictly using for loops, you'd do something like this:

```
  for(let i = 0; i < fridge.length; i++) {
    let shelf = fridge[i];
    for(let j = 0; j < shelf.length; j++) {
        let item = shelf[1][j];
        let itemSplit = item.split('')
        let newItem = 'S'+item.slice(1, itemSplit.length); 
        shelf[1][j] = newItem;
    }
  }
  console.log(fridge);
```

Third - if you're getting the results of `Top Shelf, [contents]` then that's because you are printing that array totally. The contents doesn't actually belong to the `Top Shelf` - they are different elements in the same array so `[i[k]]` won't work.

Comment: So..... Nested arrays, aren't really nested, they're just a list within the original array, in the format of an array?  I thought if i had say fridge =[['shelf', ['item']]], that item would be nested 3 arrays deep, and i could access them individualy by chaining together indices, and for loops?

Answer (score 0):

First Of all think arranging your data structure this way.

var fruits = [{'Top-Shelf': ['Milk', 'Grapes', 'Margarine'], 'Mid-Shelf': ['Beer', 'Eggs', 'Pizza', 'Soda'], 'Vegetable-Drawer': ['Celery', 'Broccoli', 'Carrots', 'Lettuce'], 'Meat-Drawer': ['Bacon', 'Turkey', 'Ham', 'Chicken']}];

when you run a for loop like:

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
console.log(fruits[i]); 
}
```

you get a logical view of your app like this in the console.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NbOn.png

Second Part of the Question, how to get subarrays?
Here is the code for that.

let fridge = [['Top Shelf', ['Milk', 'Grapes', 'Margarine']], ['Mid-Shelf', ['Beer', 'Eggs', 'Pizza', 'Soda']], ['Vegetable Drawer', ['Celery', 'Broccoli', 'Carrots', 'Lettuce']], ['Meat Drawer', ['Bacon', 'Turkey', 'Ham', 'Chicken']]];

```
var result = fridge.map((arr)=>{

    var result = ""; 

   if(Array.isArray(arr) == true){

     arr.map((arr1)=>{

           result += arr1; 

     })
   }
   else {
    result =+ arr+","; 
   }

   return result; 

}); 

console.log(result);
```

Try this code in jsfiddle.

Comment: I 100% understand why I should use an object for this, but the point is to become comfortable controlling/manipulating arrays with nested arrays, so that I don't feel uneasy about what i'm doing when a challenge asks me to manipulate nested arrays, using nested for loops.  Is this something pointless to learn the inner workings of?  I understand that in the real world for this specific application, id use an object, but is there still not use in understanding how to do this?